# Retrieving a Json String using the correct library

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to get the content of msg which is ERROR. I'm doing that by transforming string return into an array. 
Now the solution 1, works perfectly fine using `import org.json.JSONArray;`:

```
Vector<ClsReturn> ret = null;

                         ret = ds.ind(coll,uri );
                         JSONArray array = new JSONArray(" [{\"type\":1, \"txt\":\"ERROR\"}]"); 
                            int i = 0;
                            JSONObject myJsonObject = new JSONObject();
                            while(i < array.length()){
                                myJsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i); 
                                System.out.println(myJsonObject.getString("txt"));
                                i++;
                            }
```

The above solution allows me tro retrieve the content of "txt", which is "ERROR".
However (below code) when I try to use the reutrn of `String jsReturn = JSONArray.toJSONString(ret);` I'm not capable to do that because the library I'm using doesn't support `JSONArray.toJSONString`, so I need to import `org.json.simple.JSONArray;` which in turn doesn't allow me to use  `array.getJSONObject(i)` but both libraries `org.json.simple.JSONArray` and
`org.json.JSONArray` don't work together. Any workaround to get the desired outcome?

```
Vector<ClsReturn> ret = null;

                         ret = ds.ind(coll,uri );
                         String jsReturn = JSONArray.toJSONString(ret);//output(using simple.JSONArray) --> [{"type":1, "msg":"ERROR"}]
                         JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsReturn); 
                            int i = 0;
                            JSONObject myJsonObject = new JSONObject();
                            while(i < array.length()){
                                myJsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i); 
                                System.out.println(myJsonObject.getString("txt"));
                                i++;
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

`org.json.JSONArray` has a `toString()` method that will output a JSON string. It also allows for indentation by using `toString(int indent_factor)`

Comment: I tried it before but kept getting The method toString(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (Vector<ClsReturn>)